# create new table for every item of in another table on Android

Tags: java, android

I want to create a  new table in the database for every label input by the user and the table will have  two columns quiz and note but I keep getting an error. I also want to know if there are other ways to achieve this.

These are my codes:

```
package com.example.mybank;

public class SomeActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.select);
        choose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
        save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
        inputcos = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputcos);
        select = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        choose.setOnClickListener(this);
        save.setOnClickListener(this);
        select.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        loadSpinnerData();
    }


    private void loadSpinnerData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

        // Spinner Drop down elements
        List<String> lables = db.getAllLabels();

        // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);

        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        dataAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        select.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Boolean testing = true;
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.register:
                save.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                inputcos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            case R.id.save:
                try {
                    label = inputcos.getText().toString();
                    if (label.trim().length() > 0) {
                        // database handler
                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

                        // inserting new label into database
                        db.insertLabel(label);

                        // making input filed text to blank
                        inputcos.setText("");

                        // Hiding the keyboard
                        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(inputcos.getWindowToken(), 0);

                        // loading spinner with newly added data
                        loadSpinnerData();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter course",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    testing = false;
                    if (testing) {
                        if (testing) {
                            Dialog dd = new Dialog(this);
                            String error = e.toString();
                            dd.setTitle("Error");
                            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                            tv.setText(error);
                            dd.setContentView(tv);
                            dd.show();
                        }
                    }
                } finally {
                    if (testing) {
                        Dialog dd = new Dialog(this);
                        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                        if (label.trim().length() > 0) {
                            dd.setTitle("Success");
                            tv.setText("course sucessfully added");
                        } else {
                            dd.setTitle("warning");
                            tv.setText("no course input");
                        }
                        dd.setContentView(tv);
                        dd.show();
                    }
                }
                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                               long id) {
        //creating database table for each label of the list view

        if (label.trim().length() > 0) {
            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
            db.createnewtable(label);
        }


        Intent i = new Intent(this, choices.class);
        startActivity(i);
        // Showing selected spinner item


    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Database class:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "spinnerExample";

    // Labels table name
    private static final String TABLE_LABELS = "labels";
    static final String TABLE_SPINNER = "course";

    // Labels Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final  String KEY_NOTE="note";
    private static final  String KEY_QUIZES="quiz";
    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // Category table create query
        String CREATE_CATEGORIES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LABELS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL)";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CATEGORIES_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LABELS);
        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);


    }
    // creating tables for labels
    public void createnewtable(String course){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE " + course + " (" + KEY_QUIZES
                + " text not null, " + KEY_NOTE + " text not null " + ");";
        Log.i("createDB=", sql);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TABLE_SPINNER");
        db.execSQL(sql);
    }

    /**
     * Inserting new labels into labels table
     * */
    public void insertLabel(String label){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, label);

        // Inserting Row
        int i = (int)  db.insert(TABLE_LABELS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
        //Now create new table for this category
        if (i > 0) {
            createnewtable(label);}
    }
    public long insertquiz(String quiz){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_QUIZES, quiz);
        // Inserting Row
        return db.insert(TABLE_SPINNER,null, values);

    }
    public long insertnote(String note){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NOTE, note);
        // Inserting Row
        return   db.insert(TABLE_SPINNER,null, values);

    }

    /**
     * Getting all labels
     * returns list of labels
     * */
    public List<String> getAllLabels(){
        List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LABELS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                labels.add(cursor.getString(1));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // closing connection
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        // returning labels 
        return labels;}
    public  List<String> getAllquestions(){
        List<String> quiz = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery =  "SELECT * FROM TABLE_SPINNER WHERE category =" + KEY_QUIZES;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                quiz.add(cursor.getString(1));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // closing connection
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        // returning labels 
        return quiz;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which part of the code caused an error, and what was the error? Check out [how to provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You actually don't want to create tables for every item. Learn more about databases and how to filter using a WHERE statement within a single `Course` table

Comment: There's several of your queries in the format `"... TABLE_SPINNER"`, where TABLE__SPINNER is an actual variable... You aren't using the variable if there's quotes around it

Comment: Thanks for the help.I guess I didn't understand the concept of database. I have fixed the issue and it is working now.thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a list of the errors I see.

- TABLE_SPINNER is only every dropped and inserted into. Never created in `onCreate`.
- You're dropping that tablet with every call to `createnewtable`, but it was never created it.
- You're using `TABLE_SPINNER` as the correct table name in the insert statements, but it's in a string literal within the DROP and SELECT statements, so you'll very likely get a Table not found error. You need to always use your variable.
- Once the above are addressed, the insert quiz and insert note must be combined. You defined those columns as `not null`, so if you  insert one key into the content values, the other value will be null, and throw an error.
- Beware of **SQL injection** - `"SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LABELS;`

That can just be replaced by `db.query(TABLE_LABELS, null, null,...`

---

Ovrerall, you *should not* make tables based on arbitrary string values. How do you query them later? You'd have to know the name of the table to do that.

And there's no benefit of dividing any data of the same exact schema into individual tables. You instead should add a column for `String course` within a table, not create a table only for `String course`, then you filter using `WHERE course = ?`

Comment: Thanks I will check it out